# mysqldump dump only database with certain prefix

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have about 100 different databases and I want to dump with mysqldump just the ones starting with a prefix "asd_"

I tried this but it's not working:

```
mysqldump -u[user] -p[pwd] -h [server.url] asd_* --single-transaction > backup.sql
```

I tried also:

```
mysqldump -u[user] -p[pwd] -h [server.url] "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'asd_%'" --single-transaction > backup.sql
```

but does not work neither.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

mysqldump alone does not have support for wildcards for tables or databases.

You'll have to generate the list of databases as a separate step, and then use it in a mysqldump command. You can combine this step in a subcommand like this:

```
mysqldump ...options... --databases `mysql -B -N -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'asd\_%'"`
```

Note that I have to backslash the `_` character, because it's a metacharacter for `LIKE`.

I also have to use the `--databases` option, or else the second and subsequent database names will be interpreted as table names inside the first database. That's because the usage of mysqldump is one of the following:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require more complex logic than the single `LIKE` condition offers with `SHOW DATABASES LIKE ...`, an alternative is to select the table names directly:

```bash
mysqldump --databases $(mysql -Bse "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME from information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'prefix1\_%' OR SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'prefix2\_%'") > dbs.sql
```